# default resoultion for android launcher icon

Tags: android

Android icon guidelines says to use icon of size 36*36pixels for ldpi and 48*48 for mdpi 72*72pixels for hdpi (http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html). What is value that i should give as pixels per inch while creating the icon?(Photoshop shows 72 pixels/inch as default value while creating a new icon)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am quite sure that it does not matter at all. As far as I reckon, the dpi in Photoshop and other (non vectorial) image editing software is used only when you want to print the image.

If you are not convinced, try different settings for your image's dpi and check whether that changes anything.

Comment: Jhominal is absolutely correct. You can set your dpi to 3,000 if you want, but on screen you'll see no difference. DPI is dots per inch, which refers to the number of dots of printer ink that are printed in an image on paper. Although DPI is thrown around often when talking about screen resolution, the correct terminology is really PPI (pixels per inch), or pixel density. Maybe a distinction without a difference for most intents and purposes, but basically PPI is for pixels, DPI for ink/toner/what have you. :)